# backup streaming with jwplayer

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I use this js to create a jwplayer.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="embed/swfobject.js"></script>

<div id="playerContainer">player should load here</div> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
                     var flashvars = {};
                     flashvars.linkfromdisplay = "true";
                     flashvars.autostart = "true";
                     flashvars.height = "480";
                     flashvars.width = "640";
                     flashvars.volume = "90";
                     flashvars.repeat = "false";
                     flashvars.displayheight = "640";
                     flashvars.displaywidth = "480";
             flashvars.skin = "embed/minimal.zip";
             flashvars.stretching = "exactfit";
                     flashvars.file = "http://" + 
             escape("1.1.1.1/stream.php");
                     var params = {};
                     params.menu = "true";
                     params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
                     params.allowfullscreen = "true";
                     params.wmode = "transparent";
                     var attributes = {};
                     attributes.id = "playerContainer";
                     attributes.wmode = "transparent";
                     attributes.name = "playerContainer";
                    swfobject.embedSWF("jwplayer/player.swf",
 "playerContainer", "640", "480", "8","expressInstall.swf", flashvars,
 params, attributes);
</script>
```

This works fine but when there is any problem and the stream is down or not found, I want to stream another link.

Comment: You can use the JS API and onError() to do this - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Can you give me an example how to call onError() here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onError() to do this.

Here is a demo:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1442607-example-a-custom-error-message

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Displaying a Custom Error Message</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.jwplayer.com/wp-content/themes/jwplayer-105/favicon.ico">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/8/jwplayer.js'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { 
        margin: 0; padding: 0 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
jwplayer("container").setup({
    file: "rtmp://fms.12E5.edgecastcdn.net/0012E5/videos/Qvxp3Jnv-68183.flv",
    //file: "rtmp://fml.12E5.edgecastcdn.net/3012E5/tuxcast",
    image: "http://s.jwpcdn.com/thumbs/RxiqSWej-640.jpg"
});
jwplayer().onError(function(){
    jwplayer().load({file:"http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/7RtXk3vl-52qL9xLP.mp4",image:"http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/7RtXk3vl-480.jpg"});
    jwplayer().play();
});
jwplayer().onComplete(function(){
    window.location = window.location.href;
});
jwplayer().onBuffer(function(){
    theTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        jwplayer().load({file:"http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/7RtXk3vl-52qL9xLP.mp4",image:"http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/7RtXk3vl-480.jpg"});
        jwplayer().play();
    },5000);
});
jwplayer().onPlay(function(){
    clearTimeout(theTimeout);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```